# React and Redux with hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux

Long time no Redux and i am getting rusty.

I remember back to the days that we had the reducer and all the app state management went through them.

Now it is really hard to understand the workflow.

So i have my store as this.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from "../features/user";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer
  },
})
```

And this is the so called slice?

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const rootSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    value: {
      person_in: null,
      code: null,
      surname: null,
      name: null,
      active: null,
      token: null,
      org_unit: null,
      available_days: null,
      current_available_days: null,
      total_days: null,
      is_logged_in: false,
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    updateUser: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload
    }
  }
  });

 export const { updateUser } = rootSlice.actions;

 export default rootSlice.reducer;
```

So i get that if i want to update the state of the user i go with

```
dispatch(updateUser({...});
```

How can i update just the `code` attribute or any other attribute only?

Comment: I have not used redux toolkit, but have you tried state.value.code = action.payload

Comment: The "workflow" is the same: dispatch an action, and have the reducer look at the action + state to decide what the updated state should be. What's changed here is how you define the reducers, and what syntax you are allowed to use in a reducer. It's up to you to then actually write the appropriate logic for the state update you want to have happen. See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers for details on how Immer lets you write "mutating" update syntax in a reducer.

Comment: @markerikson I never thought it would be something that basic. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the ability to update a single property of your initial state object, you need to also implement the redux concept of `Action` types.

You leverage the `action.type` value within a `switch/case` statement so that you can branch and update only what you need to:  https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#handling-additional-actions.

I'm not too familiar with `reduxjs/toolkit` but it looks like their `createSlice` offers this in a slightly different but very intuitive manner:  https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation.  Wherein you add the `extraReducers` function property to your `createSlice` object.

Here is their sample code:

```
import { createSlice, createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'

const incrementBy = createAction('incrementBy')
const decrementBy = createAction('decrementBy')

const counter = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => state + 1,
    decrement: (state) => state - 1,
    multiply: {
      reducer: (state, action) => state * action.payload,
      prepare: (value) => ({ payload: value || 2 }), // fallback if the payload is a falsy value
    },
  },
  // "builder callback API", recommended for TypeScript users
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(incrementBy, (state, action) => {
      return state + action.payload
    })
    builder.addCase(decrementBy, (state, action) => {
      return state - action.payload
    })
  },
})

const user = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: { name: '', age: 20 },
  reducers: {
    setUserName: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload // mutate the state all you want with immer
    },
  },
  // "map object API"
  extraReducers: {
    [counter.actions.increment]: (
      state,
      action /* action will be inferred as "any", as the map notation does not contain type information */
    ) => {
      state.age += 1
    },
  },
})

const reducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counter.reducer,
  user: user.reducer,
})

const store = createStore(reducer)

store.dispatch(counter.actions.increment())
// -> { counter: 1, user: {name : '', age: 21} }
store.dispatch(counter.actions.increment())
// -> { counter: 2, user: {name: '', age: 22} }
store.dispatch(counter.actions.multiply(3))
// -> { counter: 6, user: {name: '', age: 22} }
store.dispatch(counter.actions.multiply())
// -> { counter: 12, user: {name: '', age: 22} }
console.log(`${counter.actions.decrement}`)
// -> "counter/decrement"
store.dispatch(user.actions.setUserName('eric'))
// -> { counter: 12, user: { name: 'eric', age: 22} }
```

In their example they update the counter (single property) state, and they update the user (object property) state.